# Control + space vim key binding in normal mode does not work

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.04, gnome-terminal

I want to map control+space to :bnext in order to forward switch in normal mode. So I added following to my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-Space> :bn<CR>
```

For backward search following

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-S-Space> :bp<CR>
```

However, this solution does not work. Any ideas on what is the problem, and how I may solve it?

**Update:** My mapping list:

```
n  [m          *@:call <SNR>45_Python_jump('?^\s*\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  [[          *@:call <SNR>45_Python_jump('?^\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  ]m          *@:call <SNR>45_Python_jump('/^\s*\(class\|def\)')<CR>
n  ]]          *@:call <SNR>45_Python_jump('/^\(class\|def\)')<CR>
   <F7>        *@:call Flake8()<CR>
n  <Tab>       * <C-W>w
n  <CR>        * :call gruvbox#hls_hide()<CR><CR>
n  *           * :let @/ = ""<CR>:call gruvbox#hls_show()<CR>*
n  ,tj           :call Tj()<CR>
n  ,st           :call Sts()<CR>           <Space>
n  /           * :let @/ = ""<CR>:call gruvbox#hls_show()<CR>/
n  ?           * :let @/ = ""<CR>:call gruvbox#hls_show()<CR>?
n  \ca           <Plug>NERDCommenterAltDelims
x  \cu           <Plug>NERDCommenterUncomment
n  \cu           <Plug>NERDCommenterUncomment
x  \cb           <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignBoth
n  \cb           <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignBoth
x  \cl           <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignLeft
n  \cl           <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignLeft
n  \cA           <Plug>NERDCommenterAppend
x  \cy           <Plug>NERDCommenterYank
n  \cy           <Plug>NERDCommenterYank
x  \cs           <Plug>NERDCommenterSexy
n  \cs           <Plug>NERDCommenterSexy
x  \ci           <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert
n  \ci           <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert
n  \c$           <Plug>NERDCommenterToEOL
x  \cn           <Plug>NERDCommenterNested
n  \cn           <Plug>NERDCommenterNested
x  \cm           <Plug>NERDCommenterMinimal
n  \cm           <Plug>NERDCommenterMinimal
x  \c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
n  \c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
x  \cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
n  \cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
n  \b          * :CommandTBuffer<CR>
n  \t          * :CommandT<CR>
v  \<Space>    * <Esc>:call gruvbox#hls_toggle()<CR>gv
n  \<Space>    * :call gruvbox#hls_toggle()<CR>
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterAltDelims * :call <SNR>17_SwitchToAlternativeDelimiters(1)<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterUncomment * :call NERDComment("x", "Uncomment")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterUncomment * :call NERDComment("n", "Uncomment")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignBoth * :call NERDComment("x", "AlignBoth")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignBoth * :call NERDComment("n", "AlignBoth")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignLeft * :call NERDComment("x", "AlignLeft")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterAlignLeft * :call NERDComment("n", "AlignLeft")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterAppend * :call NERDComment("n", "Append")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterYank * :call NERDComment("x", "Yank")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterYank * :call NERDComment("n", "Yank")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterSexy * :call NERDComment("x", "Sexy")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterSexy * :call NERDComment("n", "Sexy")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert * :call NERDComment("x", "Invert")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterInvert * :call NERDComment("n", "Invert")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterToEOL * :call NERDComment("n", "ToEOL")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterNested * :call NERDComment("x", "Nested")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterNested * :call NERDComment("n", "Nested")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterMinimal * :call NERDComment("x", "Minimal")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterMinimal * :call NERDComment("n", "Minimal")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle * :call NERDComment("x", "Toggle")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle * :call NERDComment("n", "Toggle")<CR>
x  <Plug>NERDCommenterComment * :call NERDComment("x", "Comment")<CR>
n  <Plug>NERDCommenterComment * :call NERDComment("n", "Comment")<CR>
   <F4>          :Tlist<CR>
n  <C-Space>   * :bnext<CR>
n  <S-Tab>     * <C-W>W
   <F3>          :NERDTreeToggle<CR><CR>
```

My buffers when I am trying:

```
:ls
  1 #    "views.py"                     line 73
  2 %a   "./forms.py"                   line 19
```

What cause the problem? Can you help?

Comment: Verify your keymaps show up in `:map`.  Also, they'll only do anything if there's more than 1 buffer in `:ls`.

Comment: @mtadd I updated my question please help.

Comment: I don't see your keymaps for `:bn<CR>` and `:bp<CR>` in the mapping list.

Comment: @mtadd at the bottom. Due to formatting it wasn't shown in list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `<NUL>` for this:

```
nnoremap <NUL> :w<CR>
```

saves the current file when you type `<c-space>` in normal mode.
This works for me in the terminal (I use cygwin terminal in windows, should work in other terminals).

Answer (score 14):

In most terminals (which I'm assuming you're using, since you didn't specify gVim/MacVim), `<C-Space>` and `<C-S-Space>` don't map to actual ASCII characters. You can confirm this by entering insert mode, typing `<C-V>` to initiate literal character insertion, and then typing either of those keys. If you see `^@` that means you entered the Null character, which can't be mapped to. So unfortunately you'll either need to switch to a GUI flavor of Vim (which does understand non-ASCII maps) or choose a different mapping.

Edit: my mistake, the null character can be mapped to, via `<NUL>`, as another answer points out. There's still no distinguishing `<C-S-Space>` and `<C-Space>` (or `<C-j>`, and `<C-@>`), but you can map them at least.

Comment: My terminal is Gnome Terminal.

Comment: Thank you I understand why it does not work. I will choose a different mapping.

Comment: @Phoenix, what about the default `gt` and `gT`?

Answer (score 6):

Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.